# Proper configuration steps to ensure expected text entry with AssertJ Swing tests

Tags: java, swing, junit, assertj

When using AssertJ Swing, what are the proper `@Before`/`@BeforeClass` (or other) steps to ensure entry of specific characters, such as `{`, `<`, `"`, etc.?

If I use fixture/robot methods, such as `enterText("\"")` or `pressAndReleaseKeys(KeyEvent.VK_QUOTEDBL)`, I either get "invalid key code" exceptions or wrong characters entered. The result of those methods seems to be platform dependent, no matter what I do.

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.im.InputContext;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import javax.swing.*;
import org.assertj.swing.edt.GuiActionRunner;
import org.assertj.swing.fixture.FrameFixture;
import org.assertj.swing.junit.testcase.AssertJSwingJUnitTestCase;
import org.junit.*;

public class SimplePanelTest extends AssertJSwingJUnitTestCase {

    private FrameFixture frame;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void classInit() {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMAN);
        System.setProperty("assertj.swing.keyboard.locale", "de");
        InputContext.getInstance().selectInputMethod(Locale.GERMAN);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetUp() {
         JFrame testFrame = GuiActionRunner.execute(new Callable<JFrame>() {
            @Override
            public JFrame call() throws Exception {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                f.setTitle("Test");
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.add(new MyPanel());
                return f;
            }
         });
         frame = new FrameFixture(robot(), testFrame);
         frame.show(new Dimension(720, 480));
    }

    public static class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        public MyPanel() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
            area.setName("my-field");
            add(area);
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void testSimpleTextEntry() {
        frame.textBox("my-field").enterText("\"{<");
    }
}
```

Is ensuring that developers/testers use a specific platform (keyboard layout) when writing and running tests part of how AssertJ Swing is intended to be used? Which platform? The official [documentation](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-swing-input.html) is extremely vague on this topic (it just assumes that it works for everyone).

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to simulate key events? Otherwise it might be sufficient to just set the text into your textbox by writing

```
frame.textBox("my-field").setText("\"{<");
```

I ask because there was a problem with the java robot for key combinations involving AltGr (and there might be other problems still lurking in the background):

[robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT_GRAPH) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in windows](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8155742)

Comment: I do need to simulate key events, unfortunately. I know that this is actually an issue in Java itself (I tried creating and dispatching a `KeyEvent` for `VK_QUOTEDBL` manually and it failed). But there just has to be a way to write this in a platform independent way, as in detect keyboard layout and provide a proper key mapping. I don't see how anyone could use AssertJ Swing in a meaningful way without this, except by assuming a specific platform is to be used for the test environment, always.